# Linking iOS frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, linker

When I want to use frameworks in `iOS` application, like `CoreLocation` am I supposed to link them in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`? I know it says so in the documentation for CoreLocation for example, but why does it work fine without adding this frameworks then? Same with `UIKit` for example. Why does it work without linking, and is it better to link them or not?

Answer (score 2):

When linking, an app must always know all frameworks and libraries that it uses when its symbols are referenced directly from the object code.

Since every useful iOS app requires the UIKit, it is always implicitly linked. This is a preference in Xcode, that you probably can't change. There are many other libraries (e.g. `libc`, `libm`, `libSystem`) and some frameworks (e.g. `Foundation.framework`, `QuartzCore.framework`) which are implicitly linked, too. Some libraries and frameworks are indirectly linked, e.g. Foundation includes `libSystem` and `libobjc`.

The linker must know of all of this libraries and frameworks. Thus, Xcode creates a file named `<Project>_dependency_info.dat` (e.g. `TestApp_dependency_info.dat`) located somewhere in the build folder. This file contains all libraries and frameworks which are explicitly and implicitly linked. Even for a small Hello World project in Swift this file has a size of 20kb already.

But not each app uses Core Location, MapKit, WebKit etc. or libraries like `libz` and each additional framework and library slows down the link phase. And of course, Apple can't know every (custom) framework or library you want to include in your projects. So you have to add these libraries explicitly by adding them to *Linked Frameworks and Libraries*.

This mechanism of integrating necessary frameworks automatically and optional manually is ultimately a very pragmatic approach.